# Insert, Update, Search in MySql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

This is my first post in this forum, despite being a devoted follower for years now.

I have built a simple system that registers lot numbers and their locations within a MySQL database through a PHP form.

Then i have this other form called "Errata Corrige" that I use to find and edit eventual mistaken entries.

It's search criteria is an (UNSIGNED INT UNIQUE) value named "lotto" and everything works (worked) like a charm under this circumstances.

Now the thing got a little tricky.

I found out that lot numbers (lotto) for work purposes are not always unique values, there might be more than one entry with the same number.

No problem making the "Insert" form or various counters work under this new circumstances, but it got really tricky within the EDIT functions.

This is my PHP code: `

```
<?php

$id = "";
$settore = "";
$ubicazione = "";
$numero = "";
$lotto="";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// connect to mysql database
try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error';
}

// get values from the form
function getPosts()
{
    $posts = array();
    $posts[0] = $_POST['id'];
    $posts[1] = $_POST['settore'];
    $posts[2] = $_POST['ubicazione'];
    $posts[3] = $_POST['numero'];
    $posts[4] = $_POST['lotto'];

    return $posts;
}

// Search

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $data = getPosts();

    $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM mappa WHERE lotto = $data[4]";

    $search_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $search_Query);

    if($search_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result))
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $settore = $row['settore'];
                $ubicazione = $row['ubicazione'];
                $numero = $row['numero'];
                $lotto = $row ['lotto'];
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Lotto non presente in archivio';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Error';
    }
}


// Insert
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $insert_Query = "INSERT INTO `mappa`(`settore`, `ubicazione`, `numero`, `lotto` ) VALUES ('$data[1]','$data[2]',$data[3], $data[4])";
    try{
        $insert_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_Query);

        if($insert_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                $resInsert = "1 nuovo dato inserito correttamente!";
            }else{
                $resInsert = "Nessun dato inserito";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Errore '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}


// Edit
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $update_Query = "UPDATE `mappa` SET `settore`='$data[1]',`ubicazione`='$data[2]',`numero`=$data[3],`lotto`=$data[4] WHERE `id` = $data[0]";
    try{
        $update_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $update_Query);

        if($update_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                $resAgg = "1 dato aggiornato correttamente!";
            }else{
                $resAgg = "Nessun dato aggiornato!";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Update '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
} ?>
```

`

HTML:

```
 <form action="mod.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" style="text-align:center">

    <div class="form-group has-error" style="padding-top:30px">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="state-normal">ID</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ID" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $id;?>">                                            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="state-normal">Settore</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="settore" placeholder="Settore" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $settore;?>">                                            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="state-normal">Ubicazione</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="ubicazione" placeholder="Ubicazione" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ubicazione;?>">                                            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="state-normal">Numero</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="numero" placeholder="Numero" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $numero;?>">                                            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-success">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="state-normal">Lotto</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="lotto" placeholder="Lotto" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $lotto;?>">                                            </div>
    </div>

        <div style="padding-top:16px">
            <!-- Insert-->
            <button type="submit" name="insert" value="Add" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary">Inserisci</button>
            <!-- Update-->
            <button type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-info">Aggiorna</button>
            <a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <!-- Search-->
            <button type="submit" name="search" value="Find" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-success">Cerca</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

While the lot number was unique everything worked like a charm.

Now that there are multiple data with the same lot number the code became obsolete since the "search" function only shows the last (greatest ID) data.

I have tried to work around a loop and tell the function to search every ID where lotto = lotto but it didn't work.

A simple solution would be obviously searching through **ID** instead of **lotto** but that is a pretty crapy one, since the user only knows (and is interested in) Lot Numbers not the ID it was assigned during data insertion.

Then I tried to put two php functions into one page, the first that fetches data from Mysql into a PHP dropdown menu, telling it to show every ID that matches the search criteria (lotto):

```
 <?php if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

                  include ('../mysql_connect.php');   // connessione al database

                  $category = 'lotto';
                  $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
                  $query = "SELECT * FROM mappa WHERE $category = '$criteria'";
                  $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('Impossibile reperire i dati');


                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

                            $idTab = $row['id'];
                             echo "<option>
                             $idTab </option>";


            }

              } // FINE if ?>
            </select>
```

Fetching data from MySQL into the dropdown worked just fine, but I got stucked in the syntax trying to use this dropdown as a search criteria for my first function.

**Every help would really be appreciated!** Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Within the `if(isset($_POST['search']))` you are reassigning a bunch a variables within your while loop all the time, so you will only get one result. Btw: this is a **lot** of code, please try to only put the relevant parts of your code in here, more code may be added if requested and/or needed to solve the question. As a general rule: try first with less code and add it if required or requested.

Comment: You are right about the "infinite code" . I just couldn't seem to find a way to synthesize my thoughts in a few words and a code preview!

Thank you for the prompt answer btw!

Comment: Use php's error reporting and check for errors on the queries with `mysqli_error($dbcon)`. What you have now does not help you. @AlbanB.

Answer (score 0):

You said that lotto is unique. So how come you are able to insert multiple rows with the same lotto? 
Remove the unique constraint from the lotto column.

Try the following:

```
$query = select lotto, group_concat(id) as ID numbers from mappa where lotto = 'user search number' group by lotto;
$result = $conn->query($query);
$rows = $result->num_rows;

$result->data_seek(0); //move to first row (which is the only one)
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); //fetch array

$id_numbers_string = $row[1]; //store the values of the row's second column (which is number 1)
$id_numbers_separated_array = explode(",", $id_numbers_string); //create an array with the values in the string
    for($i = 0; $i < count($id_numbers_separated_array); $i++){ //loop through created array
        echo "ID: " . $id_numbers_separated_array[$i];
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Also try to run the query in your database management system to see the results.

Comment: Hey man, thank you for the prompt answer! 

"lotto" USED TO be unique, and the first function was built given that supposition. 

Now i changed it's status to just (UNSIGNED INT) and I can insert multiple rows with the same "lotto" number. 

But now I'm stucked at modifying the EDIT function...

Comment: so problem is that there are many rows with the same lotto and you are not able to update every single one of them?

Comment: As you can see in the first function, I can either search through "id" or "lotto" and then edit the results "inline" .

If I search through ID (ID is obviously unique) everything works just fine. But the user doesn't know (and doesn't care) about the lot id, he/she knows the lot number. 

If I search through "lotto" it will only show me one (of many) lot number (the one with the greatest ID number). 

So it's more a problem of "search & find" . 

How can I search thorugh lot number (let's say: 10) and make the function tell me: ID 10, 11, 12 match your criteria, search through them (?)